# Bubble Sort using a while loop in Python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I've been set a bubble sort for homework, and I've been trying to use a while loop. I know that it's possible with a for loop, but I don't really understand them and I'd like to write something that I understand.

```
unsorted = True
numbers = []
unsortchecker = 0
start = 0
maxlist = int(input("How many numbers should be sorted?"))
if len(numbers) == 1:
   print(1)
while len(numbers) < maxlist:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    numbers.append(num)
while unsorted:
    if unsortchecker == 0:
        unsorted = False
    while start != maxlist:
        if numbers[start] > numbers[start+1]:
            replacement = numbers[start]
            replaced = numbers[start+1]
            del numbers[start]
            del numbers[start+1]
            numbers.insert(start, replaced)
            numbers.insert(start+1, replacement)
            unsortchecker = 1
            start = start + 1
            print(numbers)
      else:
          start = start + 1
          print(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

When I run this, it will work for the first few, and then replace different numbers to what I want, and then give back an error 
IndexError: list index out of range
Any ideas?

Edited Code

```
unsorted = True
numbers = []
unsortchecker = 0
start = 0
maxlist = int(input("How many numbers should be sorted?"))
end = maxlist
if len(numbers) == 1:
    print(1)
while len(numbers) < maxlist:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    numbers.append(num)
while unsorted:
    if unsortchecker == 0:
        unsorted = False
    start = 0
     while start < maxlist-1:
        if numbers[start] > numbers[start+1]:
            replacement = numbers[start]
            numbers[start] = numbers[start + 1]
            numbers[start + 1] = replacement
            unsortchecker = unsortchecker + 1
            start = start + 1
            print(numbers)
        else:
             maxlist = maxlist - 1
             print(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: "I know that it's possible with a for loop, but I don't really understand them and I'd like to write something that I understand."

If you are *learning* to program, that is a *terrible* mindset. If you don't understand them now, put in some work so you understand them.

Comment: What is the exact error? At what line is the index out of range?

Comment: I'm learning the for loop, but if I could use a while loop on this which I understand I would much prefer it.

Comment: Your identation is still wrong btw.

Comment: The error is on line 15

Comment: Okay, now two more things. Remove one level of indentation from the `start = start + 1`, and also remove the `else:` and put the `maxlist = maxlist - 1` into the same indentation as the `while`.

The `start` variable needs to be incremented after each comparison, not only if the comparison is positive.

The `maxlist` variable needs to be decremented after each run of the innermost while loop

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters:

```
replacement = numbers[start]
replaced = numbers[start+1]
del numbers[start]
del numbers[start+1]
numbers.insert(start, replaced)
numbers.insert(start+1, replacement)
```

This looks like a very cumbersome way to swap the two numbers. Try this way:

```
replacement = numbers[start]
numbers[start] = numbers[start + 1]
numbers[start + 1] = replacement
```

And no need for `del` and `insert`. Understand what these three lines do: I put the value that's at position `start` into the variable `replacement`. Then I overwrite the value at position `start` with the value at position `start + 1`. Then I overwrite the value at position `start + 1` with the value in `replacement`, which is the old value of `numbers[start]`.

There's an even more efficient way (in python, anyway) to swap numbers, but it could be a bit confusing for starters.

That's not the only problem though.

The way you have implemented BubbleSort is that you "bubble up" instead of "bubble down". That means that after the very first pass, you now know that the largest element will be at the end of the list.

This means that instead of increasing `start` by 1 after the first pass, you'd have to reduce the *upper* end by 1.

Comment: `numbers[start], numbers[start+1] = numbers[start+1], numbers[start]` is much more pythonic

Comment: That's what I was hinting at with "more efficient way" but let's not confuse beginners with tuple assignments ;)

Comment: It's because if `start` has run up all the way to `maxlist - 1` (the last step before the loop isn't run any more), then `numbers[start + 1]` will be `numbers[maxlist]` which is out of range. So really your condition in the loop should be for `maxlist - 1` instead of `maxlist`.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the difference between "bubbling up" and "bubbling down". If it runs for the same amount of time is there no difference? Also, is it wrong to have the largest element at the end.

Comment: Next up, before entering the innermost while-loop you'd have to reset `start` to 0, and in the `else` part instead of `start = start + 1` do `maxlist = maxlist - 1`.

Comment: And, finally, instead of using `!=`, use `<`.

Comment: The difference is this: In traditional bubble sort, after the first innermost loop, the largest element is at the end. That is good, and I call that "bubbling up". You could write a modified algorithm where instead of that, after the first pass the smallest element is at the front.

Comment: I think I've entered it all correctly, but i just get them returned in the given order, without any switching place.

Comment: I couldn't fit it in a comment so have added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

The bubble sort algorithm works in **O(n*n)** time by [repeatedly swapping adjacent elements](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Bubble-sort-example-300px.gif) with each other to ensure sort order. Its popular publicized form with two for loops can easily be modified to replace with while loops as expressed below:

```
def bubbleSort(l):
    i = 0
    while i<len(l):
        j = 0
        while j<len(l)-1:
            if l[j+1] < l[j]:
                l[j], l[j+1] = l[j+1], l[j]
            j += 1
        i += 1
    return l
```

Python enables swapping without a temporary variable which makes the code look a lot more readable.

Comment: Well, in your innermost line l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i], you don't have a guarantee that j = i + 1, so i, j are not adjacent elements and so you're not doing classic BubbleSort

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that algorithm exits if there is nothing else to do, you can add a test.

```py
def bubblesort_using_whileloop():
    sortFinished = False
    while sortFinished is False:
        sortFinished = True
        for i in range(len(list)-1):
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
                sortFinished = False
```

Comment: Please, avoid using python predefined functions, such as `sorted`. Besides, while I see what improvement you suggest, you should explicit it. Generally speaking code-only answer should be avoided. But when answering old questions, that already have working answers, it is particularly important to explain what is new in your answers (even if, question has 5 years now. If Tom hasn't returned his assignement to his teacher by now, it is probably too late). I edit your answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the consideration and guidance provided.

Answer (score 0):

At this particular line:

```
if numbers[start] > numbers[start+1]:
```

numbers[start+1] is referencing an element in your list that does not exist (outside the boundaries of the array).

```
while len(numbers) < maxlist:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    numbers.append(num)
```

In this line of code, you are adding numbers to a list until your list length is equal to the max length. Let's say maxList is equal to 10. Your list would contain 10 elements once it has exited this loop.

```
 while start != maxList:
        if numbers[start] > numbers[start+1]:
        #extra code here
        start = start + 1
```

In this while loop, you are iterating through each element of the array and incrementing the start variable each time. If say maxList is equal to 10, once start = 9, your while loop evaluates 9 != 10 (start != maxList) and proceeds. Your next if statement if numbers[start] > numbers[start+1] then tries to compare if numbers[9] > numbers[10]. Lists and array indexes in Python start at 0, therefore, when you are trying to reference the element at numbers[10], you are referencing the 11th value in the list, which doesn't exist. This is a common "off by one" error that you will encounter often in your programming adventures! :) To correct this, simply change your while loop to:

```
while start <= maxList:
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a `for loop` with a definite number of iteration(s) is potentially wasteful. It fails to accommodate the scenario where a already sorted array is given. The `for loop` would blindly iterate regardless of whether the array is sorted or not.

Instead, we should introduce a flag and use a `while loop`. As soon as it detects no swapping, it's done.